# Use Multithreading To Speed Up Pandas Dataframe Creation

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, bigdata, text-analysis

The problem I'm having, and there doesn't seem to be any answers out there, is that I need to process a very large textfile (the gmdnTerms.txt file from GUDID), manipulate the data to merge lines with duplicate IDs, create appropriate columns for the key value pairs, and dump the results to a CSV file. I've done everything I can think of to increase efficiency except to implement multithreading. I need to be able to multithread the process of iterating over the text file and building the dataframe. The multithreading tutorials weren't much help. Hoping an experienced Python programmer can give a clear answer. Below is the entire program. Please help, current run time is >20 hours on a 4.7GHz proc (8 cores) with 16GB RAM and an SSD.

```
#Assumptions this program makes:
#That duplicate product IDs will immediately follow each other
#That the first line of the text file contains only the keys and no values
#That the data lines are delimited by a "\n" character
#That the individual values are delimited by a "|" character
#The first value in each line will always be a unique product ID
#Each line will have exactly 3 values
#Each line's values will always be in the same order

#Import necessary libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import mmap
import time

#Time to run
startTime = time.time()

#Parameters of the program
fileLocation = "C:\\Users\User\....\GMDNTest.txt"
outCSVFile = "GMDNTermsProcessed.csv"
encodingCSVFile = "utf-8"

#Sets up variables to be used later on
df = pd.DataFrame()
keys = []
idx = 0
keyNum = 0
firstLine = True
firstValue = True
currentKey = ''

#This loops over each line in text file and collapses lines with duplicate Product IDs while building new columns for appropriate keys and values
#These collapsed lines and new columns are stored in a dataframe
with open (fileLocation, "r+b") as myFile:
    map = mmap.mmap(myFile.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for line in iter(map.readline, ""):

        #Gets keys from first line, splits them, stores in list
        if firstLine == True:
            keyRaw = line.split("|")
            keyRaw = [x.strip() for x in keyRaw]
            keyOne = keyRaw[0]
            firstLine = False

        #All lines after first go through this
        #Collapses lines by comparing the unique ID
        #Stores collapsed KVPs into a dataframe
        else:
            #Appends which number of key we are at to the key and breaks up the values into a list
            keys = [x + "_" + str(keyNum) for x in keyRaw]
            temp = line.split("|")
            temp = [x.strip() for x in temp]

            #If the key is the same as the key on the last line this area is run through
            #If this is the first values line it also goes through here
            if temp[0] == currentKey or firstValue == True:

                #Only first values line hits this part; gets first keys and builds first new columns
                if firstValue == True:
                    currentKey = temp[0]
                    df[keyOne] = ""
                    df.at[idx, keyOne] = temp[0]
                    df[keys[1]] = ""
                    df.at[idx, keys[1]] = temp[1]
                    df[keys[2]] = ""
                    df.at[idx, keys[2]] = temp[2]
                    firstValue = False

                #All other lines with the same key as the last line go through here
                else:
                    headers = list(df.columns.values)
                    if keys[1] in headers:
                        df.at[idx, keys[1]] = temp[1]
                        df.at[idx, keys[2]] = temp[2]
                        else:
                        df[keys[1]] = ""
                        df.at[idx, keys[1]] = temp[1]
                        df[keys[2]] = ""
                        df.at[idx, keys[2]] = temp[2]

            #If the current line has a different key than the last line this part is run through
            #Sets new currentKey and adds values from that line to the dataframe
            else:
                idx+=1
                keyNum = 0
                currentKey = temp[0]
                keys = [x + "_" + str(keyNum) for x in keyRaw]
                df.at[idx, keyOne] = temp[0]
                df.at[idx, keys[1]] = temp[1]
                df.at[idx, keys[2]] = temp[2]

        #Don't forget to increment that keyNum      
        keyNum+=1

#Dumps dataframe of collapsed values to a new CSV file
df.to_csv(outCSVFile, encoding=encodingCSVFile, index=False)

#Show us the approx runtime
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - startTime))
```

Comment: How large is your input file?

Comment: An input sample and output sample would also help.

Comment: @Steve Here is the test input data https://pastebin.com/z8nKX22t and here is the results of that data (Open it as CSV) https://pastebin.com/dhmtKbGE

Comment: Ah ok, how large is the input file? I want to know if it can fit in memory

Comment: @Steve Sorry there, forgot to include the size of the actual file. It is about 880MB in size.

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee that this is faster but give it a try and let me know how it goes, it runs correctly and quickly against your sample data

```
import csv
import itertools
import sys

input_filename = sys.argv[1]
output_filename = sys.argv[2]

with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_file, \
     open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
    input_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='|')
    header = next(input_reader)
    header_1_base = header[1]
    header_2_base = header[2]
    header[1] = header_1_base + '_0'
    header[2] = header_2_base + '_0'
    current_max_size = 1
    data = {}
    for line in input_reader:
        line[0] = line[0].strip()
        # line[1] = line[1].strip()
        # line[2] = line[2].strip()
        if line[0] in data:
            data[line[0]].append(line[1:])
            if len(data[line[0]]) > current_max_size:
                current_max_size += 1
                header.append('{0}_{1}'.format(header_1_base, current_max_size - 1))
                header.append('{0}_{1}'.format(header_2_base, current_max_size - 1))
        else:
            data[line[0]] = [line[1:]]

    output_writer = csv.writer(output_file, lineterminator='\n')
    output_writer.writerow(header)
    for id in data:
        output_writer.writerow(itertools.chain([id], itertools.chain(*data[id])))
```

It doesn't make use of pandas dataframe since your goal seems to be to convert to the csv format, instead it uses a simple python dictionary. There is no multithreading in this version either though some could be added later on if necessary. I'd guess the largest bottle neck you will run into is if your system runs out of memory and starts swapping then there are other methods we can look at to speed it up.

Update - the above is for python3 to convert it to python2 change:

```
output_writer.writerow(itertools.chain([id], itertools.chain(*data[id])))
```

to

```
output_writer.writerow([x for x in itertools.chain([id], itertools.chain(*data[id]))])
```

Comment: I ran it locally against the same dataset, yet I got an 'output_writer.writerow(itertools.chain([id], itertools.chain(*data[id])))_csv.Error: sequence expected' I am running this on Python 2.7.14

Comment: ah, this is written for python3

Comment: Incredible results! It ran two orders of magnitude faster your way (1.19 seconds down to 0.019 seconds). What do you think caused the slowdown in my original method? Pandas? All the loops to compare the headers? something else? Thank you so much for the help, really helped me learn here (and save myself and my company a lot of time).

Comment: A lot of stuff :) You could probably get more performance out of it if you really wanted to though. I didn't profile so this is just speculation...1) using the csv library to iterate through the file instead of reading each line and splitting it 2) pandas keeps track of a lot of information to provide all its features that comes with some memory and performance cost 3) computing the key for every row 4) python creates a new string with each strip call 5) lots of temporary lists 6) reducing memory foot print - the moment this consumes all your memory it will slow down a LOT.

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation. I'll take those factors into account in the future, and I'll remove using Pandas from doing simple text to csv manipulation like here. I think I was really not using the right/most efficient tool for the job. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help! :)